# "conda activate base" whenever I run a python script in VS code with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I just set up visual code with the Python Path redirecting to anaconda3 (both fresh installations) as such:
[Python Path redirecting to anaconda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhx2A.png)

It works fine except that whenever I run something the first input will be filled with "conda active base" as you can see here (the line "Execute :" is an input): [First input with "conda active base"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIAvE.png)

If I run something that has no inputs, the script will finish running, and in the next prompt "conda active base" appears along with this error message:[Script runs but new prompt gets "conda active base"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3VN1.png)

How can I fix/avoid this problem? All I am looking for is to have anaconda in sync with visual studio (as it is right now, except for this error)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you`re using Windows, you have to add PATH variables.

For Windows 10 (buttonnames depending on your systemlanguage):

1. Press Windows Button on your keyboard and type "env". Open the first result "Edit the system environment variables".
2. A window with "System Properties" will open. Click on button below "Environment Variables"
3. In the upper half "User variables fo HP" should be a "Path" entry. Select it and click "Edit", else click "New".
4. Add two new entries for "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3" and "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Scripts" if not exists
5. Confirm with "Ok" and repeat the same for the lower half "System variables"
6. Sometimes a reboot is required to make changes work

If you´re using an older Windows Version, the steps are closely the same, maybe some buttons have different names. You can find many instructions when searching for "Windows XX change PATH variable".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an unix based OS, run

```
where anaconda
```

This shall give you the path where anaconda is installed in your system something like `/home/username/anaconda3`

open the `bashrc` or `zshrc` or `bash_profile` based on the OS and shell you are using.

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add a your anaconda path to system path:

```
export PATH=/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Make sure you include the `bin` directory where your python interpreter resides.

Answer (score 0):

in your vscode Search Select interpreter.
select interpret python.
and select the environment you want to be activated when you run python.